# Converting small C# checksum program into Java

Tags: c#, java, checksum

I'm trying to build a simple ground control station for an RC airplane. I've almost finished it, but I'm having a LOT of trouble with the checksum calculation. I understand that the data types of Java and C# are different. I've attempted to account for that but I'm not sure I've succeeded. The program utilizes the CRC-16-CCITT method.

Here is my port:

```
public int crc_accumulate(int b, int crc) {
        int ch = (b ^ (crc & 0x00ff));
        ch = (ch ^ (ch << 4));
        return ((crc >> 8) ^ (ch << 8) ^ (ch << 3) ^ (ch >> 4));
}

public byte[] crc_calculate() {
        int[] pBuffer=new int[]{255,9,19,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,81,4,3};
        int crcEx=0;
        int clength=pBuffer.length;
        int[] X25_INIT_CRC=new int[]{255,255};
        byte[] crcTmp=new byte[]{(byte)255,(byte)255};
        int crcTmp2 = ((crcTmp[0] & 0xff) << 8) | (crcTmp[1] & 0xff);
        crcTmp[0]=(byte)crcTmp2;
        crcTmp[1]=(byte)(crcTmp2 >> 8);
        System.out.println("pre-calculation: 0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[0]&0xff))+" 0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[1]&0xff))+";   ushort: "+crcTmp2);
        if (clength < 1) {
                System.out.println("clength < 1");
                return crcTmp;
        }
        for (int i=1; i<clength; i++) {
                crcTmp2 = crc_accumulate(pBuffer[i], crcTmp2);
        }
        crcTmp[0]=(byte)crcTmp2;
        crcTmp[1]=(byte)(crcTmp2 >> 8);
        System.out.print("crc calculation: 0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[0]&0xff))+" 0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[1]&0xff))+";   ushort: "+crcTmp2);
        if (crcEx!=-1) {
                System.out.println("  extraCRC["+crcEx+"]="+extraCRC[crcEx]);
                crcTmp2=crc_accumulate(extraCRC[crcEx], crcTmp2);
                crcTmp[0]=(byte)crcTmp2;
                crcTmp[1]=(byte)(crcTmp2 >> 8);
        System.out.println("with extra CRC:  0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[0]&0xff))+" 0x"+Integer.toHexString((crcTmp[1]&0xff))+";   ushort: "+crcTmp2+"\n\n");
        }
        return crcTmp;
}
```

This is the original C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArdupilotMega
{
class MavlinkCRC
{
    const int X25_INIT_CRC = 0xffff;
    const int X25_VALIDATE_CRC = 0xf0b8;

    public static ushort crc_accumulate(byte b, ushort crc)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            byte ch = (byte)(b ^ (byte)(crc & 0x00ff));
            ch = (byte)(ch ^ (ch << 4));
            return (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ (ch << 8) ^ (ch << 3) ^ (ch >> 4));
        }
    }

    public static ushort crc_calculate(byte[] pBuffer, int length)
    {
        if (length < 1)
        {
            return 0xffff;
        }
        // For a "message" of length bytes contained in the unsigned char array
        // pointed to by pBuffer, calculate the CRC
        // crcCalculate(unsigned char* pBuffer, int length, unsigned short* checkConst) < not needed

        ushort crcTmp;
        int i;

        crcTmp = X25_INIT_CRC;

        for (i = 1; i < length; i++) // skips header U
        {
            crcTmp = crc_accumulate(pBuffer[i], crcTmp);
            //Console.WriteLine(crcTmp + " " + pBuffer[i] + " " + length);
        }

        return (crcTmp);
    }

}
}
```

I'm quite sure that the problem in my port lies between lines 1 and 5. I expect to get an output of 0x94 0x88, but instead the program outputs 0x2D 0xF4.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me where I've gone wrong.

Thanks for any help,
Cameron

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the original code, and your attempt at a port, here, in the body of your question rather than as links.

Comment: At my first look, you use different types for crc calculation. Why not try using same (or similar) datatypes, with proper casts?

Comment: @Cameron: please post your code of interest here. Many won't go to links out of concern for contamination or can't go to links due to firewalls.

Comment: Your problem almost certainly has to do with sign extension.  byte in C# is unsigned, byte in Java is signed.  So a byte with value of 255 becomes -1 when you assign to an int.

Comment: @karoberts: Yes that is very possible. When I converted the C# program to Java, I changed C#'s "byte" into Java's "int".

Comment: Perhaps it is the "unchecked" part, which I ignored completely? I know what it does, thanks to Google, but am not quite sure how to implement it in Java.

Comment: @CameronLattz `unchecked` turns off compile-time checks for integer overflows. Java doesn't do such checks at all.

Comment: @millimoose: Oh, I misunderstood what I had read. Thank you.

Comment: @karoberts While you're probably correct about the reason for the problem, that example didn't make sense. A Java `byte` can never have the value of 255. The value of the bit pattern `0xFF` interpreted as a `byte` in Java will be -1, and if you assign from such a `byte` variable to an `int` variable it will remain -1.

Comment: @karoberts Now, what *can* happen is the opposite: an `int` variable with the value `255` being assigned to a `byte` variable. Then it would indeed wrap around and the value of the `byte` variable would be `-1`. (I have no idea where in the OPs code this would cause problems though.)

Comment: Are you sure it should be `0x94 0x88`? Running the C# with `crc_calculate(new byte[] { 255, 9, 19, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 81, 4, 3 }, 15)` gives me `0xFC 0x7E`.

Comment: @CameronLattz Have you tried adding identical detailed debugging output to both programs to see when exactly the intermediate results start to diverge? As in, between any lines of code that do any calculation, etc.

Comment: @millimoose: No, I have never compiled C# before, but as you can tell from my code I tried debugging EVERY line of Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, for starters lets clean up the C# code a little:

```
const int X25_INIT_CRC = 0xffff;

public static ushort crc_accumulate(byte b, ushort crc)
{
    unchecked
    {
        byte ch = (byte)(b ^ (byte)(crc & 0x00ff));
        ch = (byte)(ch ^ (ch << 4));

        return (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ (ch << 8) ^ (ch << 3) ^ (ch >> 4));
    }
}

public static ushort crc_calculate(byte[] pBuffer)
{
    ushort crcTmp = X25_INIT_CRC;

    for (int i = 1; i < pBuffer.Length; i++) // skips header U
        crcTmp = crc_accumulate(pBuffer[i], crcTmp);

    return crcTmp;
}
```

Now the biggest problem here is that there are no unsigned numeric types in Java, so you have to work around that by using the next bigger numeric type instead of `ushort` and `byte` and masking off the high bits as needed. You can also just drop the `unchecked` because Java has no overflow checking anyway. The end result is something like this:

```
public static final int X25_INIT_CRC = 0xffff;

public static int crc_accumulate(short b, int crc) {
    short ch = (short)((b ^ crc) & 0xff);
    ch = (short)((ch ^ (ch << 4)) & 0xff);

    return ((crc >> 8) ^ (ch << 8) ^ (ch << 3) ^ (ch >> 4)) & 0xffff;
}

public static int crc_calculate(short[] pBuffer) {
    int crcTmp = X25_INIT_CRC;

    for (int i = 1; i < pBuffer.length; i++) // skips header U
        crcTmp = crc_accumulate(pBuffer[i], crcTmp);

    return crcTmp;
}
```

For the input in your question (`{ 255, 9, 19, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 81, 4, 3 }`) the original C#, cleaned up C# and Java all produce `0xfc7e`.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect such a speedy and complete response! Thank you very much. I have to go to work now but will test it as soon as I get back. Thanks again!

Comment: I've applied your code to my program and I too get 0xFC 0x7E as output. I was expecting 0x94 0x88 because of a LabView calculator someone provided, but since your cleaned up C# and the C# of the code are nearly identical, I'm sure it's an error in the LabView calculator. Thanks!

Comment: @CameronLattz As I said at the end of my answer, the original C# code in your link also results in `0xfc7e`. Maybe double check the input array, it's possible you missed an entry or transposed a digit, etc.

Comment: Actually, the problem was I forgot to add in a "crc extra" (which I had included in my original Java program but forgot to mention). Now that I've done that the output IS 0x94 0x88. This problem has been bugging me for weeks- it's crazy that verdesmarald solved it in a few minutes! Thanks again, you were a huge help.